# How do I write a WHERE statement to match dates on the last day of the month?

Tags: sql, sybase

I am querying a time series database table and I want to return data where the `created_date` is on the last day of the month (End of Month). The schema looks like this:

```
|     int     |  varchar(12) |  smalldatetime | 
| primary key |     data     |  created_date  |
```

and the query I want to write is something like

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where create_date IS end_of_month
```

Is there a built in function for this in Sybase? If not, what would the logic be to create a query like this? Can it be done without writing a function?

I've been able to write a function to get the last day of the month for any given month. What I'm looking for now is a way to match on all given End of Months.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dateadd and removeing one day DATEADD(day,-1,1stDayOfMonth)

```
-- Date format mm/dd/yyyy and calculate the last day of month m-1 
-- example for 03/23/2015 dateadd calulate => 28/02/2015

DATEADD(day,-1, RTRIM (cast(datepart(mm,getdate()) as varchar(2)))+'/01/'+cast(datepart(yyyy,getdate()) as  varchar(4)) )
```